# C++ doubly linked list

Tags: c++

I got a problem with my doubly linked list. How can i make the input unique ( i don`t want it to be repeated )
for example i can input 1 and then again 1 i will have a list of 1 and 1. I need to forbid this somehow :) so the list can contain only not repeating numbers.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
    node* prev;
};
class Node
{
    public:
        Node();
        ~Node();
        void setKopa();
        void printForward();

     private:
        node* head;
        node* tail;
        node* n;
};
Node::Node()
{
    setKopa();
}
Node::~Node()
{
    delete n;
}
void Node::setKopa()
{
    int lenght;
    do
    {
        cout << "Input list lenght (how many elements): ";
        cin >> lenght;
        if(lenght<2)
        cout << "Error list has to have atleast 2 elements!" <<endl;
    }
    while(lenght<2);

    int fill;
    cout << "Input  "<< lenght <<" elements: "<<endl;

    for (int i=0; i<lenght; i++)
    {
        cin>>fill; 
        n = new node;
        n->data = fill;

        if (i==0)
        {
            n->prev = NULL;
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        else if (i+1==lenght)
        {
            n->prev = tail;
            tail->next = n;
            tail = n;
            tail->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            n->prev = tail;
            tail->next = n;
            tail = n;
        }                           
    }
}
void Node::printForward()
{
    node* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp-> next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    Node a;
    a.printForward();    

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be unique in the whole sequence, or you just want to forbid subsequences of one repeating element?

Comment: The code is poorly designed. a list should show `add`, `remove`,`contains` etc.. and not the mysterious `setKopa()` which read from user input.

Comment: while(temp != NULL)
    {
       if(input == temp->data )
        
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read input, go through the list to see if the input is already there.

---

With that (simple) answer out of the way, I would like to address some other things regarding your code. The first is that you have a memory leak in that you never delete the list. The second is that you don't need the class member variable `n`, it might as well be a local variable inside the `setKopa` loop.

Your way of adding new nodes is also, well, weird. It should, in my opinion, be more general instead of using the loop counter to check what to do. What I suggest is that you make a member function to add new nodes, taking the integer data as argument. This way you can call this function to add nodes anywhere, and not just in the `setKopa` function. In fact, I think the list should not handle that input at all, instead it should be a free-standing function called from `main` and which calls the `addNode` function.

Also the `node` structure doesn't need to be in the global namespace, it could be a private structure in the `Node` class. And speaking of the `Node` class, shouldn't it really be called `List` instead?

So if I may suggest, you might want to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class List
{
public:
    List()
        : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr)
     {}

    ~List();

    void addNode(const int data);

    void printAll() const;

private:
    struct node
    {
        node()
            : next(nullptr), prev(nullptr)
        {}

        node* next;
        node* prev;
        int   data;
    };

    node* head;
    node* tail;
};

List::~List()
{
    for (node* next, *cur = head; cur; cur = next)
    {
        next = cur->next;
        delete cur;
    }
}

void List::addNode(const int data)
{
    node* n = new node;
    n->data = data;

    if (tail == nullptr)
    {
        // First node in list
        head = tail = n;
    }
    else
    {
        n->prev = tail;
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
    }
}

void List::printAll() const
{
    std::cout << "{ ";
    for (node* cur = head; cur != nullptr; cur = cur->next)
        std::cout << cur->data << ' ';
    std::cout << "}\n";
}

int main()
{
    List list;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        list.addNode(i);

    list.printAll();
}
```

The above code should print

```
{ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 }
```

Replace the node-adding loop with your own.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful. Can you explain the memory leek more deeply?

Comment: @JurisKušta You have x number of nodes in your list, but you only free one, the one pointed to by `n`, which will be the last one added.